# Relation between Spring Container and implementation of BeanFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-context

I'm beginner with Spring and I have issues understanding how those two work. I will work my question through example.

We have project with Spring Core module, in that project we have two classes annotated with `@Component` in different packages and one main class in third package.

Now we create three different `@Configuration` classes and on one we specify `@ComponentScan(package with first @Component annotated class)` lets call it config1 and on seconds we specify `@ComponentScan(package with second @Component annotated class)` lets call it config2 and on third we specift `@ComponentScan(both packages)` lets call it config3.

Now in main class we have following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  // point 1 in time
  System.out.println("lalalalalala");

  // point 2 in time
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context1 =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(config1.class);

  // point 3 in time
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context2 =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(config2.class);

  // point 4 in time
  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context3 =
                new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(config3.class);
}
```

My understanding:

At point 1 in time, we have our application with Spring Core running. At this point Spring created Container and it has no objects. Its empty.
[Point 1 in time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIcHE.png)

So then we create object of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` type. We send config1 class as parameter to this object. Then this object will read `@ComponentScan` annotation and scan for POJO's and metadata. After scanning, `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` object will create beans (1 bean in this example, and its eager loading with this type of context) and place them in Spring Container. So at this point in our application we, for the first time, have something in our Spring Container.
[point 2 in time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG2wG.png)
Object of type `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`  will only have reference to bean that we put in Container?! So when we call `getBean()` method, our Context will "bring" bean from Container?

Same thing happen with [point 3 in time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgMYV.png), and [point 4 in time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fejCB.png)...

So, basically my question here is: Object that is some kind of implementation of `BeanFactory`, READS POJO's and metadata, CREATE BEANS and PLACE them into Spring Container? It does not hold beans, it only points at those beans that are in Container? And Container only contains those beans, he doesn't have any function except holding beans, like its  just place in memory? And also we only have one Container in our application, we can have multiple BeanFactory objects but only one Container?

Comment: Point 1 has nothing no Spring Container. The Spring Container IS the application context. So in your code you have 3 Spring Containers as Spring Container == ApplicationContext.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I understand now.